# Mysql - innoDb - is in the future! Current system log sequence number

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have this error in my syslog. I restored an older dump to solve this problem, after some reading. Now The errors in syslog are far less than before.

But still a few times an hour I get

```
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: 120901 14:23:29  InnoDB: Error: page 96637 log sequence number 7 1223357717
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 6 647303887.
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: for more information.
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: 120901 14:23:29  InnoDB: Error: page 96638 log sequence number 8 150027924
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 6 647303887.
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: for more information.
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: 120901 14:23:29  InnoDB: Error: page 96639 log sequence number 7 4208567151
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 6 647303887.
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
Sep  1 14:23:29 homer mysqld: InnoDB: for more information.
```

Anybody that knows how I can track what database is causing this issue? And how to fix?

Comment: Looks there's an answer there : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/any-better-way-out-of-mysql-innodb-log-in-the-future

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been migrated to [dba.se] but is now too old to migrate.

Answer (score 4):

There is inconsistency between the data files and the ib_logfile[0|1]-s.
For me this can happen if I didn't run --apply-log when using innobackupex.

Try shut down the server, move the ib_logfiles into a different directory, and restart process. New logfiles will be created. 
(If it fails again, you can move back the original files)

Comment: I had this innodb is in the future message after resetting a broken slave using xtrabackup and could not work out why:  I'd forgotten the --apply-log step - documentation now updated!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Only 2 hours of chasing my tail.